# Converting csv to xls using Data::Table::Excel?

Tags: perl, automation, perl-module

How do you use `Data::Table::Excel` for converting `.csv` to `.xls` file format.

I want to do the conversion with the `tables2xls` subroutine:

```
my $t = Data::Table::fromFile("testresults-2013-07-01.csv");  
my @arr = $t->csv;  
Data::Table::Excel::tables2xls("results.xls", $t ,\@arr);
```

I tried the code above but I was not able get what I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last line must be:

```
Data::Table::Excel::tables2xls("results.xls", [$t] ,["Sheet name for your Table"]);
```

And here is colors example like you want:

```
Data::Table::Excel::tables2xls("results.xls", [$t] ,["Sheet name for your Table"], [["white","silver","gray"]]);
```

Comment: wonderful, but need data encoded in windows cp1252 , with utf8 data I got encoding problems , any solution to work with utf8 data ?

Comment: @Sérgio give me more details please. What is your source CSV encoding and what XLS encoding you expect?

Comment: @gangabass 
I have to do , something like : 
open(FCSV, ">:encoding(cp1252)", "$file.csv");
print FCSV $csv->string();
my $table = Data::Table::fromFile("$file.csv");
Data::Table::Excel::tables2xlsx("$BASExlsx", [$table], ["something"], [["white","silver","gray"]]);
or utf-8 characters appears double encoding